# Cropping UIImage by custom shape

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have a background UIImage, and I would like to crop the background UIImage with a custom shape so this background image only "appears" through the custom shape. For example, I have a moon-shaped custom shape, and I would like the background image to only come through on the moon-shaped part.

Based on another answer, I am trying to impose a mask on the image like so:

```
- (UIImage *)createImageFromImage:(UIImage *)image
                    withMaskImage:(UIImage *)mask {
    CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;
    CGImageRef maskRef = mask.CGImage;

    CGImageRef imageMask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                             CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                             CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                             CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef),
                                             NULL,
                                             YES);

    CGImageRef maskedReference = CGImageCreateWithMask(imageRef, imageMask);
    CGImageRelease(imageMask);

    UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:maskedReference];
    CGImageRelease(maskedReference);

    return maskedImage;
}
```

However, the result of this looks like [image], and there are several issues with it:

1. the moon I have is 100*100, this has stretched do a strange proportion
2. My goal is only for the image to come through the moon - however, at the moment the moon is a white shape that is coming over the image

Any ideas about how I could fix the crop issue would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can use this library for any custom shape. Just draw your path and you get cropped image. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mdimagecroper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your background image you'll have to add a custom mask through `CALayer`.
Keep in mind, everything you color in the mask.png (moon) will be visible, everything *transparent* will not display.

```
UIImage *moonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.png"];
CALayer *maskLayer = [CALayer layer];
[maskLayer setContents:(id)moonImage.CGImage];
[maskLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, moonImage.size.width, moonImage.size.height)];

UIImageView *yourBackgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
// Keep your image view in tact here, just add:
[yourBackgroundImageView.layer setMask:maskLayer];
```

Comment: This worked great, and achieved exactly the result I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @daspianist I need exact behaviour. Where should I write the above code ?